# Getting some weird strings while i was trying to get location name using marker on touch event on maps

Tags: android, geolocation, location, maps

I'm trying to make an app to get the location name where the marker is placed on the map in android. When I used `marker.position()`  function it gave me a weird string. Starts with,  `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions@28f817d`

I tried to use geocode but didn't work for me. I might be using it in an improper way.

```
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                mMap.clear();
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
                mMap.addMarker(marker.position(point)
                        .draggable(true)
                        .title(String.valueOf(marker.position(point)))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                        .snippet(point.latitude + "," + point.longitude));
            }
        });
    }

I wish that I can get the location name on the title.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                mMap.clear();
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
                mMap.addMarker(marker.position(point)
                        .draggable(true)
                        .title(getAddress(point.getLatitude(),point.getLongitude()))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                        .snippet(point.latitude + "," + point.longitude));
            }
        });
    }
```

write a function called getAddress like this

```
public string getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add); 
        return add;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: we can't use .title(getAddress(point.getLatitude(),point.getLongitude())) like this ,android studio showing an error.

Comment: sorry,i forgot to return the title from the method.I have edited my answer.please check

Answer (score 0):

Thats becouse marker.position(point)) returns an object of class [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) and is not an String itself. You could use any of its properties (latitude & longitude):

```
String.valueOf(marker.position(point))
```

to

```
"" + marker.position(point).latitude + marker.position(point).longitude
```

Comment: I applied this syntax but showing me an error cannot resolve symbol latitude and longitude.